# How to limit the launch of programs that do not have a digital signature?

Tags: windows, operating-systems, windows-server, administration

the virtual machine Windows 12 r2. It is necessary to limit the launch of programs without a digital signature. Heard about SRP, tried to use, did not work, I do not understand what exactly is needed. I ask for help.

Purpose: There are two sets of files - signed / unsigned. It is necessary to check that the OS blocks unsigned files and verify that the signed files are working. Break the digital signature and check the files as the OS responds.

How to do it? Desirable instruction or link!

Comment: *Windows 12 r2*...Do you mean **Windows Server 2012 R2**? Please [edit] your question to include this correction.

Comment: I think that what we can have is that when we click the programs without a valid  digital signature, it will pop up an error/warning that the program you want to run is not safe.........

Comment: Use Applocker GPO policy - you can identify your app by different ways there (location, name, file, etc.)